# Proving that $HC\subset V_{\omega_1}$

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the class of all hereditary countable sets, $HC=\{x: |tc(x)|\leq\omega_0\}$ is a subset of $V_{\omega_1}$. Here $tc(x)$ denotes the transitive closure. I've already proven that $HC$ is a transitive class; Now I tried using $\in$-induction:

Let $X=\{x: x\in HC\rightarrow rank(x)<\omega_1\}$ and suppose that $x\subset X$. Our goal is to prove that $x\in X$. Suppose that $x\in HC$. Then, if $y\in x$, since $HC$ is transitive, we have that $y\in HC$; but $y\in X$ too, therefore $rank(y)<\omega_1$. Now since $\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal, it will be $rank(y)+1<\omega_1$. Now $y$ was arbitrary, so $\sup\{rank(y)+1: y\in x\}\leq\omega_1$. But this is exactly $rank(x)$, therefore $rank(x)\leq\omega_1$.

Now I can't rule out the case where $rank(x)=\omega_1$. Any hints?

Comment: $x $ is countable, and you are using choice.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Since $x\in HC$, it is $|x|\leq |tc(x)|\leq\omega_0$, therefore $x$ is countable. It is $\sup\{rank(y)+1: y\in x\}=\bigcup_{y\in x}(rank(y)+1)$, a countable union of countable sets -since $rank(y)+1<\omega_1$ for all $y$- therefore $rank(x)<\omega_1$ and we use choice to get that countable union of countable sets is countable, Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andrés: Amusingly, I am just finishing a paper with David today, and it will include a choiceless definition for $H(\kappa)$, along with a proof that $H(\kappa)\subseteq V_\kappa$, that doesn't use choice. :)

Comment: @Asaf  You should post a sketch at some point as an answer.

Comment: @Andrés: Yeah, after I post the paper on arXiv, I will be sure to come here and make that point. ;)

Comment: @Andrés: Well, the announcement is tomorrow, but the paper is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very nice observation:

The following are equivalent for any set $x$:

1. The von Neumann rank of $x$ is $\alpha$, and
2. $\alpha=\min\{\beta\mid\operatorname{tcl}(x)\cap V_{\beta+1}\setminus V_\beta=\varnothing\}$.

Using this claim, if $x\notin V_{\omega+1}$, then its transitive closure has an obvious map onto $\omega_1$, and is therefore not countable, so $x\notin\rm HC$.

The proof of the claim is by $\in$-induction on $x$:

Note that $\operatorname{tcl}(x)=x\cup\bigcup\{\operatorname{tcl}(y)\mid y\in x\}$. If $\beta<\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the rank of $x$, then for some $y\in x$, the rank of $y\geq\beta$. Apply the induction hypothesis to $y$, and obtain that $\operatorname{tcl}(x)\cap V_{\beta+1}\setminus V_\beta$ is not empty.

In the other direction, note that if the rank of $x$ is some $\alpha'>\alpha$, then there is some $y\in x$ whose rank is at least $\alpha$, so in $\operatorname{tcl}(x)$ there is some $y'$ whose rank is $\alpha$, and therefore $\operatorname{tcl}(x)\cap V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_\alpha\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Ok, this is cute.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty darn cute. It also gave a cool new definition for $H(\kappa)$ as $\{x\mid\kappa\nleq^*\operatorname{tcl}(x)\}$. This is the proof that $H(\kappa)$ is in fact a set. (Oh noes, I spoiled the best part, and no nobody will read the paper! ;))

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04077